# Redmine - how to add an activity in the DDL

Tags: redmine

Wow.I cant believe how raw redmine setup is.

Anyway..I wanted to update a ticket in a project and there is a activity drop down list.  I cant save unless I specify an activity.  There is none.  How do I populate a list of activities from the UI?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Time tracking activities: The content of the drop-down are in the global setting, [relevant redmine guide link](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineEnumerations).

By the way, if you don't enter anything for *spent time* and the related *comment* in the *Log time* section, you don't have to select an activity.